# How to decode a python code , Encrypted with Zlib, Marshal, Base 64?

Tags: python, encoding, base64, zlib, decoding

I want to decode code like this

```
_ = lambda __ : __import__('marshal').loads(__import__('zlib').decompress(__import__('base64').b64decode(__[::-1])));exec((_)(//code in encrypted form))
```

how can i do that ?

Anyone know how to do this